# How can I click the downloaded file when viewing chrome://downloads/

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

As part of my automation test, in my ruby *capybara* feature spec, I attempted to write a test where from the chrome browser, after downloading a PDF file, I go to the `chrome://downloads/` and want to be able to click the file to open it up; however because of the shadow-roots dom objects, I am unable to click the link. Is there a solution out there to achieve this?

Below is what I've tried where it complains about:

```
NoMethodError:undefined method `find' for #Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x007f96dba3ba78
```

The code is:

```
        visit 'chrome://downloads'
        sleep(1)
        root1 = find('downloads-manager')
        shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
        
        root2 = shadow_root1.driver.browser.find_element(:css, 'iron-list')
        shadow_root2 = expand_shadow_element(root2)

        root3 = shadow_root2.find('downloads-item')
        shadow_root3 = expand_shadow_element(root3)
        
        file_link = shadow_root3.find("file-link")
        file.link.click

    def expand_shadow_element(element)
        shadow_root = execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
        return shadow_root
    end
```

Comment: Are you sure you can? That page isn't a real web page.

Comment: Why are your tests testing Chrome? You should trust that Google did that already.

Comment: @tadman yes, I've been able to do that with selenium python binding using the body/deep combinator to access shadow DOM tree. I'm trying to find a solution in selenium ruby binding.

Comment: @aridlehoover I only posted the relevant excerpt of my test code here. Additional detail of why I'm doing this is so I can click the pdf file(that was generated from my previous test) to open it up then I can grab a screenshot and then call my image comparison method to assert if the screenshot matches with a base image that I have in another directory. So here I'm only looking for a way to click the file from chrome://downloads  to open it for me to grab the screenshot.

Comment: Got it. So, it's a true end-to-end test. My bet is that Chrome always puts downloaded files in the same folder. You could open the file directly from that location rather than trying to do it in the browser.

Comment: @aridlehoover you are correct. So I modified my test code so now once it clicks to save the file, since it always saves to the downloads folder, I just open the file directly from the location and then using the RMagick gem to convert .pdf to .png and able to save the converted .png file to the desired location from where I can pick it up and have it compared against the base image for my assertions. So it all works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call Capybara methods on a native selenium-webdriver element.  The reason you have a native selenium-webdriver element is that you're using `execute_script` which shouldn't be used when you're expecting a return value - instead you should be using `evaluate_script`

```
def expand_shadow_element(element)
  evaluate_script('arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
end
```

or in recent versions of Capybara

```
def expand_shadow_element(element)
  element.evaluate_script('this.shadowRoot')
end
```

That will then wrap the returned selenium-webdriver element in a Capybara element and allow use of the methods you expect. No guarantees on how well that works with shadow dom though since support for shadow isn't in the webdriver spec yet so there's not a ton of support for it in selenium-webdriver.

Comment: Thank You ! I will try that and get back.